# convert datetimeindex to Qx-YY format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with table that looks like

```
Date        Open
11/1/2016   59.970001
10/3/2016   57.41
9/1/2016    57.009998
8/1/2016    56.599998
7/1/2016    51.130001
6/1/2016    52.439999
5/2/2016    50
4/1/2016    55.049999
```

I only need quarterly date rows (mar, jun, sep, dec) and convert the date columns to Q1-16/ Q2-16/ Q3-16 etc.

Code:

```
DF_sp = pd.read_csv(shareprice,  index_col = 'Date', parse_dates =[0])
DF_Q= DF_sp.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('Q')).nth(-1)
DF_Q['Qx-YY'] = ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then [`dt.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) with [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html), but first need convert [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.to_period('Q')).Open.mean()
print (df)
Date
2016Q2    52.496666
2016Q3    54.913332
2016Q4    58.690000
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: Open, dtype: float64

df.index = 'Q' + df.index.to_series().dt.quarter.astype(str) + '-' 
               + df.index.to_series().dt.year.astype(str).str[2:]
print (df)
Date
Q2-16    52.496666
Q3-16    54.913332
Q4-16    58.690000
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.to_period('Q')).Open.mean()
print (df)
Date
2016Q2    52.496666
2016Q3    54.913332
2016Q4    58.690000
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: Open, dtype: float64

y = df.index.strftime('%y')
df.index = df.index.quarter.astype(str)
df.index = 'Q' + df.index + '-' + y
print (df)
Q2-16    52.496666
Q3-16    54.913332
Q4-16    58.690000
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

The best is use [`period.Period.strftime`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/pandas.tseries.period.Period.strftime) - link from old documentation but works very well:

```
df = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.to_period('Q')).Open.mean()
print (df)
Date
2016Q2    52.496666
2016Q3    54.913332
2016Q4    58.690000
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: Open, dtype: float64

df.index = df.index.strftime('Q%q-%y')
print (df)
Q2-16    52.496666
Q3-16    54.913332
Q4-16    58.690000
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

Comment: this is not idiomatic ; use .strftime with a Period index if you really need to format it as a string (which is not recommended at all)

Comment: @Jeff - but how get quarter in strftime? I cannot find solution for it.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-span-representation

Comment: @Jeff - Thank you, I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: i think u could actually leave it as a period after u asfeq to Q

Comment: yes, it is the best, but OP dont want it - see [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524617/convert-datetimeindex-to-qx-yy-format/40524965?noredirect=1#comment68289848_40524691)

Comment: @j.j - Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `1` above accepting mark. Thanks.